# Are humans known to be "poisonous" to any animal?

Tags: human-biology

Are there examples of non-herbivorous animals that could be poisoned if they feed on humans because of the composition of our bodies/blood?

Comment: Human is not in the menu of other animals (in normal circumstances) and there aren't any studies regarding to this (as you can guess) so we don't know if human meat is toxic to any other animal. There are instances where other animals ate human though (for example: great white sharks and lions). On the other hand,  cannibalism can lead to a disease called [Kuru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuru_(disease)) which is caused by abnormally folded prion proteins. Thus, we could say human meat is toxic for humans.

Comment: Hmm, [this "non-science related" book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=UqdCDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT183&lpg=PT183&dq=%22human+meat+can+be%22&source=bl&ots=6cvEgb2U-9&sig=E2_8LCi1lX48ilO4NB0sVvzoieU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD9ZaP7uzYAhUh24MKHaQXC5kQ6AEIZTAN#v=onepage&q=%22human%20meat%20can%20be%22&f=false) claims that: "Human meat can be poisonous for protected species like crocodiles."